# Create lazy xarray object from Future

Tags: python, python-xarray, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I have a `dask.delayed` function that takes an `xarray.Dataarray` as an argument and returns one as well.

I'm creating a few of these delayed tasks and pass them to `client.compute` using `dask.distributed`. Each call to compute returns a `distributed.client.Future` representing the data array that will be returned.

My question is:

Is there a way to build a "lazy" data array again from the future without loading the actual data from the worker? My intention is to built a second task graph based on the output from the first computation.

I've seen `client.gather` but this seems to pull all the data back to the client, which is not what I want.

Here's a small example:

```py
import dask
from distributed import Client
import xarray as xr

# load example data
x = xr.tutorial.open_dataset("air_temperature")

# use first timestep
x_t0 = x.isel(time=0)

# delayed 'processing' function
@dask.delayed
def fun(x):
    return x*2

# init client
client = Client()

# compute on worker
future = client.compute(fun(x_t0))

# when done
print(future)
# <Future: finished, type: xarray.Dataset, key: fun-96cd56f4-4ed3-4eac-ade9-fe3f17e4b8c6>

## now how to get back to lazy xarray from future?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what you are exactly trying to achieve in the end. There might be better ways to do that than creating a new array from the future. That being said, this will create a new data array from your data:
You have to not call compute to keep it lazy.

(if you want a dask array instead of a xarray array remove the xr.DataArray)

```
import dask
from distributed import Client
import xarray as xr

# load example data
x = xr.tutorial.open_dataset("air_temperature")

# use first timestep
x_t0 = x.isel(time=0)

# delayed 'processing' function
@dask.delayed
def fun(x):
    return x*2

# init client
client = Client()

# Create lazy xarray object from future:
import dask.array as da

new_ds = xr.DataArray(da.from_delayed(client.persist(fun(x_t0)), shape=x_t0.air.shape, meta='f8'), coords=x.coords)
```

**EDIT:** added client.persist to leave data on client

output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I should have been more explicit: I need the metadata (coordinates, etc.) from the dataarray, so just plainly wrapping a dask array into a `xarray.Dataarray` is not a solution for me. +1 for a workable solution

Comment: Thanks, I hope this works: x['new'] = ((tuple(x_t0.coords)[:2], da.from_delayed(client.persist(fun(x_t0)), shape=x_t0.air.shape, meta='f8'))   ?  This will create a new parameter in your dataset, over the existing dimensions..

Comment: or you can use: new_ds = xr.DataArray(da.from_delayed(client.persist(fun(x_t0)), shape=x_t0.air.shape, meta='f8'));       new_ds. assign_coords(x.coords)       to create a new ds with the array from the delayed in it?

Comment: the example in your second comment does pretty much what I want (and what I hoped there could be a native way). One note, you could put everything in one call if you call `xr.DataArray` with `coords=x.coords`. If you'd like to add this into your solution, I'd accept it as an answer! Thanks again!

Comment: Ok great, I added it. Thanks for pointing that out!